# How to use Event notification in Solaris 10 when a directory changes?

Tags: events, solaris, ports

I read Robert Benson's article "[The Event Completion Framework for the Solaris Operating System](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/event_completion.html)" on ECF.

I also read the Solaris man pages but they are not very clear of how to use event notifications for directories.
For example, if I add a new file into a directory, I would like to get some notification of that event.

I found "[File Events Notification](http://blogs.oracle.com/praks/entry/file_events_notification)" which has what I need but it is for Solaris 11, which is not in the market yet.

Based on "[Event ports and performance](http://blogs.oracle.com/dap/entry/event_ports_and_performance)", I don't want to use poll because I want to get the performance advantage of events.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Comment: Depending on your requirements, OpenSolaris (SunOS 5.11) is already in the (free) market.

Comment: No, unfortunately I will have to use Solaris 10. I found a library called Libev but it doesn't work for directory changes in Solaris.
I'm aware of libevent but it is to slow for my program. If you know any C or C++ based event library that would be great!

thanks for the response.

-Armando.

Answer (score 1):

Event ports are a generic mechanism not specific to file or directory changes.

There wasn't support to generate these events for file or directory changes until NV build 72 (after Solaris 10 was released).